# Unequal study groups and non parametric tests

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, unbalanced-classes

I have two groups that are particularly unequal 111 vs 29 persons in each group and i would like to know if the Mann-Whitney U test works fine in this case also. I know from previous discussions that when the two groups are not similar 1:2 ratio this works fine. But what about an almost 1:4 allocation?

Comment: A number of other answers on site deal with a variety of large ratios of sample size. It doesn't matter if it's a million vs 3.

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter. With more even allocation you would have more power to reject the null hypothesis, if there is in truth a tendency to have higher/lower values in one of the groups compared to the other. Otherwise there is no issue.